# Using Scala with Gradle for Android project

Tags: android, scala, intellij-idea, gradle

There seems to be a memory leak somewhere.

When setting up a project in IntelliJ and using the Gradle wrapper:

`./gradlew assembleDebug --debug`

I get the following after about 5 mins:

```
14:30:15.245 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] processing scala/collection/SeqViewLike$$anon$5.class...
14:30:53.132 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] processing scala/collection/SeqViewLike$$anon$6.class...
14:33:51.027 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] 
14:33:51.028 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
14:33:51.028 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
14:33:51.028 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project]   at java.util.HashMap.<init>(HashMap.java:209)
14:33:51.029 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project]   at com.android.dx.ssa.LocalVariableInfo.<init>(LocalVariableInfo.java:66)
14:33:51.029 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project]   at com.android.dx.ssa.LocalVariableExtractor.<init>(LocalVariableExtractor.java:72)
14:33:51.029 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project]   at com.android.dx.ssa.LocalVariableExtractor.extract(LocalVariableExtractor.java:54)
14:33:51.029 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project]   at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaConverter.convertToSsaMethod(SsaConverter.java:49)
14:33:51.030 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project]   at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:98)
14:33:51.030 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project]   at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:72)
14:33:51.030 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project]   at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:303)
14:33:51.030 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project]   at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:139)
14:33:51.031 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project]   at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:94)
14:33:51.031 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project]   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:682)
14:33:51.031 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project]   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
14:33:51.031 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project]   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
14:33:51.032 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project]   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
14:33:51.032 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project]   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
14:33:51.032 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project]   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
14:33:51.034 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project]   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
14:33:51.034 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project]   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
14:33:51.034 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project]   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
14:33:51.034 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project]   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
14:33:51.035 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project]   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
14:33:51.035 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project]   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
14:33:51.035 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project]   at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

I am using `Scala 2.9.3` but experienced the same problem with `2.10.x`.

Here is my `build.gradle`.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'

    // Scala.
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.9.3',
            'org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.9.3'
}
```

Is anyone successfully compiling an Android project with Gradle + Scala.

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a sample project I found that maybe of help to some. https://github.com/yareally/android-scala-intellij-no-sbt-plugin

Comment: You can still create Intellij + Scala + Android (non Gradle) project. Just add scala specific proguard file and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks mate. Think I might go this approach. Gradle looked fun though.

Comment: If you want to develop android Apps with Scala this is probably what would you want: https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to dex a whole Scala library. You have 2 options here:

1. Try to increase heap size. You can read how to do it in [this group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/P_TLBTyFWVY). However this will not solve build time issues.
2. Try to use proguard before actual dexing.